Ghost.io Blog "style" variable
I'm working on a Ghost Theme and with the given Ghost Theme I'm working on there's a code that checks for equality of style to 'one' or 'two':{{#match style "one"}}
and {{#match style "two"}}
When I check for {{style}} in my case it equals "two".
My question is where can I set the value for style within Ghost.io so I may set it to 'one' and see how the website looks with style set to 'one'?
